# Mysql multi connections with atomic update sql queries [Race condition]

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I'm currently working on a project in nodejs that has a pool connection to Mysql DB ( with like 10 connections open at the same time ).
And now I want to able the connections to update tables in the DB like so:

```
update table set tries=tries+1 where condition=value;
```

My question is there is no way that will be here a race condition between all the connections with this approach?
because I've looked up on the internet and found that "transactions" in my SQL will cause a race condition between multi DB connections.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Make your transaction's isolation level as serializable. In case of updation, use Optimistic locking. Write these in StoredProcedure.

```
DECLARE V_ERR_OCCURED   BOOLEAN;
DECLARE V_ERR_MESSAGE   VARCHAR(500);

SET V_ERR_OCCURED=FALSE;
SET V_ERR_MESSAGE=SPACE(0);

SET V_ERR_MESSAGE='Transaction Error';

BEGIN

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
SET V_ERR_OCCURED=TRUE;

SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
START TRANSACTION;

# Your Update Statements

IF V_ERR_OCCURED=TRUE THEN
    ROLLBACK;
ELSE
    COMMIT;
END IF;

SET AUTOCOMMIT=1;

END;
```